# pandas.DataFrame.to_latex is too wide

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I have a Pandas `df` and I m calling `to_latex`. Everything is good apart from the fact that the table is too wide for the page I wanna print it into. Since it is indeed too wide, but not too much, I m ready to shrink it a little. And normally I would do this with a resize box.

Is there a way to tell Pandas directly in the call to `to_latex` that I wanna do a resize box?

Comment: i think you can use matrix2latex package

Comment: @AlexisDrakopoulos I d rather avoid